# Centering a View inside the parent view using Autolayout constraints

Tags: ios

I have a self.photoView which is of type UIView and I have photoImageView which is UIImageView. I want to center the photoImageView X and Y inside the self.photoView.

This code is not doing anything!

```
let photoImageView = UIImageView.imageViewForPhotoTaken(self.photoView.bounds, image: img)
            photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

            self.photoView.addSubview(photoImageView)

            // set the autolayout constraints 
            self.photoView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.photoView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: photoImageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
```

Comment: I want to align the sub view (photoImageView) center horizontal and center vertically.

Comment: You need to create a constraint for both axis, and more than likely you should also be declaring a height and width constraint ... your code doesnt' indicate that the UIImageView is supposed to be any size other than zero

Comment: does your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints = false` on `photoView` and `photoImageView` before yo add the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
let photoImageView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: "logo"))
photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
self.photoView.addSubview(photoImageView)
photoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// set the autolayout constraints
self.photoView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: photoImageView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.photoView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.photoView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: photoImageView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.photoView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

If you want center in horizontal and vertical both you should set both 'Center X' and 'Center Y' constraint

Also please make sure you have put proper constraint for the 'self.photoView' before setting this

you should place this code may be at 'viewDidAppear' or any method which is called after this